# How to retrieve single value with grep from Json?

Tags: shell, grep

How to extract a single value from a given json?

```
{
  "Vpc": {
    "InstanceTenancy": "default", 
    "State": "pending", 
    "VpcId": "vpc-123", 
    "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16", 
    "DhcpOptionsId": "dopt-123"
  }
}
```

Tried this but with no luck:

```
grep -e '(?<="VpcId": ")[^"]*'
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You probably wanted `-Po`, which works with your regex:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<="VpcId": ")[^"]*' infile
vpc-123
```

If GNU grep with its `-P` option isn't available, we can't use look-arounds and have to resort to for example using grep twice:

```
$ grep -o '"VpcId": "[^"]*' infile | grep -o '[^"]*$'
vpc-123
```

The first one extracts up to and excluding the closing quotes, the second one searches from the end of the line for non-quotes.

But, as mentioned, you'd be better off properly parsing your JSON. Apart from [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) mentioned in another answer, I know of

- [Jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/)
- [JSON.sh](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh)

A jq solution would be as simple as this:

```
$ jq '.Vpc.VpcId' infile 
"vpc-123"
```

Or, to get raw output instead of JSON:

```
$ jq -r '.Vpc.VpcId' infile 
vpc-123
```

Comment: Thanks, but P option is not supported out of the box on Mac OS X El Capitan. I don't want to install add-ons.

Comment: @Centurion I think it's not possible in a single grep command then, I've added a solution that uses grep twice.

Comment: If the json is stored in a variable try this: 
`echo $json | grep -o '"VpcId": "[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$'`

Comment: @thomasvanstone I declined that edit because it didn't seem to be correct; trying to access a non-existing field just returns `null`, and doesn't cause a jq error. And trying to access something that *would* cause an error is better done using the [optional object identifier-index](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#OptionalObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo?), `?`, and still not grep.

Answer (score 6):

Something like

```
grep '^ *"VpcId":' json.file \
  | awk '{ print $2 }' \
  | sed -e 's/,$//' -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'
```

Answer (score 5):

you can do:

```
sed -r -n -e '/^[[:space:]]*"VpcId":/s/^[^:]*: *"(.*)", *$/\1/p'
```

but really, using any shell tools to run regexes over JSON content is a bad idea.  you should consider a much saner language like `python`.

```
python -c 'import json, sys; print(json.loads(sys.stdin.read())["Vpc"]["VpcId"]);'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex pattern:

```
\"VpcId\":\s?(\"\S+\")
```

Comment: Nop, doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

If you can install a tool I would suggest using jq [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). It allows very simple grep, with great support for piping too.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks for solutions using grep. In case he means using terminal, the node cli is an alternative, since support for JSON is total. One alternative could be the command node --eval "script"

```
echo '{"key": 42}' \
| node -e 'console.log(JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync(0).toString()).key)' //prints 42
```